# how can you set the top and left of a background image in css

Tags: css, image

i am looking at a page which has an image on it.  i see that in the css, the image is set as a background but the image is not at the top of the page.  So my basic questions is trying to understand the css below

```
#p_background {
    background:url(/Content/images/test.gif) no-repeat center 108px;
}
```

in particular, what does the **center** and **108px** represent?

Comment: http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a short form of:

```
#p_background {
    background-image:url(/Content/images/test.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 108px;
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: yes. The format of background position is xposition yposition.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the 'shorthand' code specifying the properties of the background of that div.  It could be expressed this way:

```
background-image:url('/Content/images/test.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:108px;
```